# Every restart need to mount home

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I have 2 hard disks, dual boot.

lsblk

```
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 137.1G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   450M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0    86G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0  46.6G  0 part /usr
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0 418.1G  0 part /home
└─sdb6   8:22   0   1.1G  0 part [SWAP]
```

sda1 is shared by Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Windows 10, and sdb is /usr, /home and SWAP partitions.

Each restart I'm entering the "emergency mode" which prompts me to press `Ctrl+D` for maintenance. If I do so, I go to root console, and when I mount my home (`mount /dev/sdb5 /home && exit`) I can boot to Ubuntu.

I've checked `/etc/fstab` and it have the following line

```
UUID=39a7245e-38be-45c6-98fc-482cec6ae979 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

and `ls -ltr /dev/disk/by-uuid/` clearly states that:

```
39a7245e-38be-45c6-98fc-482cec6ae979 -> ../../sdb5
```

I'm a bit lost here, how do I automatically mount the disk?

Comment: Are you able to fsck the sdb drive before manually mounting it? In a terminal window, type `fsck -f /dev/sdb`. Let us know. Cheers, Al

Comment: If you write this as answer, I accept it. mount failed because of errors on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion, you may have some file system errors on sdb. When you're in the root window in emergency mode, check the filesystem by typing `fsck -f /dev/sdb` (or `fsck -f /dev/sdb5`). Run the fsck more than once, until you get a clean run. Let me know how you do. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

Although the majority of grub is installed on sdb there is a small boot secton installed by grub on sda. Whenever you update kernel or change grub menu, and other grub parameters the regular `sudo update-grub` command doesn't change sda. You need to type `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`.

Comment: Is there a way to be sure where my grub is installed?

Comment: @Anton Open Nautilus and click on the `Computer` option in the left pane. In the right pane you'll see the `Boot` folder. Click on it and you'll see most of the grub files. There are some other configuration files in other directories too. Let me know if `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` doesn't work for you so I can revise the answer as necessary.

Comment: Looking again at your sda from my computer and not smart phone this time grub may be on sda and not sdb. I haven't had your multi-partition setup before spanning two disks. It could be `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` doesn't improve over `sudo update-grub` in your case and does the very same thing. Let me know how things work out.